# How to get the correct number of spaces in a recursive sequence of diamonds?

Tags: c++

Currently at my Programming I university class we've been going over recursive functions. I was presented with an exercise that demanded I created a sequence of diamonds with asterisks using a recursive function so that if the input was an integer n, the program would print the sequence of diamonds for n-1, then the diamond for n, and then again the sequence for n-1.

It's tricky to explain it correctly (I would copy what we are asked for in the exercise but it just says to "look at the provided examples"), so here's the list of the sample public cases I am provided with so you can see what exactly I'm referring to: [Public cases for the sequences of diamonds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CKNy.png)

The code I have created is the following:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void diamonds(int n) {
    if ( n == 1 ) {
        cout << '*' << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << ' ';
        diamonds(n - 1);
        for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; ++j) {
                cout << ' ';
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < 2 * i + 1; ++j) {
                cout << '*';
            }
        cout << endl;
        }
        for (int i = n - 2; i >= 1; --i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; ++j) {
                cout << ' ';
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < 2 * i + 1; ++j) {
                cout << '*';
            }
        cout << endl ;
        }
        cout << ' ';
        diamonds(n - 1);
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    diamonds(n);
}
```

The problem is that the output has the number of asterisks I need in each line, but I can't seem to get the correct number of spaces before every line of asterisks so that the whole sequence of diamonds is centered. Does anyone know how I could solve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have to add extra parameter (the max n) to your `diamond` to be able to compute number of space correctly. As printing a diamond 2 alone won't have extra space, but a diamond 2, whereas it is for diamond 4 would requires extra prefix space.

Comment: If I can give a little precision to the above comment, you output a space right before calling `diamonds(n - 1);`. Imagine `n = 3`, then `diamonds(n-1)` is going to spread on 3 lines. That space you are adding is only going to impact the first line of `diamonds(n-1)`. Starting on the 2nd line onward, it is going to be missing.  **Regarding the recursion, make sure to prefer inequality stop conditions over equality tests. It is safer to do `if (n <= 1)` rather than `if (n == 1)` to stop the recursion.** I hope the reason is obvious.

Comment: Unrelated to my previous comment, another issue your code has is that it is obscure. I get it that everyone uses `i` and `j` as default names for index variables for loops. However, could you perhaps have chosen better names such as `r`, standing for rows, and `c`, standing for columns?

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j < 2 * i + 1; ++j) { cout << '*'; }` could be replaces with `cout << string(2 * i + 1, '*');`.   Just sayin'.